# sql-left-outer-join-with rows-based on column value from right table

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables `Table A` and `Table B` with `many-to-one` relationship, i.e for every record in `Table A`, there may be one or multiple rows in `Table B`. I am `Left Outer` joining `Table A` with `Table B` on columns : `A.Employee_Id = B.Employee_Id`.

For example, for `Employee 1` in `Table A`, there may be two rows in `Table B`: first row `Event_ID = "R"` and second row `Event_Id= "S"`. For `Employee  2`, there may be only one row with `Event_Id ="R"`.

So basically, I want the rows in `Table B` to be sorted for every employee based on column value of `Event_Id` in the order "F", "S" and "R" and then pick the first row from this order, to be joined with `Table A`.

And I want only one record to be returned in the result for every employee. (Of course, NULL values if there are no records).

Please suggest how can this be done in an optimised way.

```
Table A Columns:
Employee_Id,  First_Name,  Last_Name

Table B Columns:
Employee_Id, Event_Id, Event_Comment
```

Comment: You can use an [outer apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) if you're using sql-server.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB with row_number()

```
select a.Employee_Id, a.First_Name, a.Last_Name,
       b.Event_Id, b.Event_Comment   
from TableA a
     left join
     (select Employee_Id, Event_Id, Event_Comment,
             row_number() over(partition by Employee_Id 
                               order by case Event_ID 
                                        when 'F' then 1 
                                        when 'S' then 2 
                                        when 'R' then 3 end) as rw
    ) b
    on a.Employee_Id = b.Employee_Id
where rw is null or rw = 1;
```

Ansi SQL (but there still may be several rows for each employer - if tableB has the same EventIds for one employer):

```
select a.Employee_Id, a.First_Name, a.Last_Name,
       tmp.Event_Id, tmp.Event_Comment
from 
tableA a 
 left join 
 (select Employee_Id, Event_Id, Event_Comment 
  from TableB b
        join (select Employee_Id, min(case Event_ID 
                                     when 'F' then 1 
                                     when 'S' then 2 
                                     when 'R' then 3 end) as min_event
            from TableB group by Employee_Id
           ) t 
       on t.Employee_Id = b.Employee_Id
          and t.min_event = case b.Event_ID 
                             when 'F' then 1 
                             when 'S' then 2 
                             when 'R' then 3 end
 ) tmp                                       
 on a.Employee_Id = tmp.Employee_Id;
```

Comment: The first query worked perfectly for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: This made my day. Same solution can be used with `ORDER BY ISNULL(rowname) ASC` to select the first row with a not null value if it exists, otherwise select the row with a null value. Excellent performance as well. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You didnt give a schema so winging it a bit here but something like below should work:

```
      SELECT CASE WHEN B.EVENTID = 'F' THEN '1'
                  WHEN B.EVENTID = 'S' THEN '2'
                  ELSE '3' END AS ORDER,
      A.EmployeeId,
      B.EventId 
        FROM TableA AS A
        LEFT JOIN TableB AS B
        ON A.EmployeeId = B.EmployeeId
        GROUP BY A.EmployeeId,B.EventId
        Order by A.EmployeeId DESC
      Where ORDER = '1'
```

Comment: This will give all rows from `B`, OP mentioned he only need the first row.

Comment: Adding a rownumber with partition and select just where row number = 1 given the bit I didnt read properly. May need to have a nested select here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. One more problem here is, event id values "F" ,"S","R" do not fall properly in the descending category. So any suggestion to give preference to row "F" first, "S" next and  "R" last ?

Comment: Add a forth column with a case statement (F=1,S=2,R=3) and order by that instead of EventId in the RowNumber. Although if you do that you can probably get rid of the rowNumber altogether

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. The case statements solved the problem.